# Gradle: Nest jar inside directory

Tags: gradle

I want to create a new directory, and a new jar inside that directory, like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

version = '1.0.2'
group = 'com.prosc.sample'


task directoryWithJar(type: Copy) {
    destinationDir = file("dir")    
    
    from (
        file('readme.txt'),
        file('docs.txt'),
        Jar {
            archiveFileName = 'archive.jar'
            from( file( 'picture.png' ) )
        }
    )
}
```

However, when I try that, I get this error:
***Could not find method Jar() for arguments [build_329zrj9mpox02efrc7ksg64ii$_run_closure1$_closure2@1a9efa5] on task ':directoryWithJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.***